# spring websocket, how to implement @sendtouser

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

I want to create a chat in persons who are watching the same video. but I don't know the implementation of @sentTouser in spring. I want to create a similar java anotation @sentToVideo so that I can just add a method in controller and add this new anotation, and then the method return values can send to the video chat via websocket. Then how to start ? what should I learn in spring ? is there anybody could help me ?